# Regex for a number which can starts with 0

Tags: javascript, regex, ng-pattern

I use this regex for my field:

```
/^([1-9]([0-9]){0,3}?)((\.|\,)\d{1,2})?$/;
```

What I want to do is to allow the user to enter 0 as a beginning of the number, but in this cas, he must enter at least a second digit diffrent from 0 and the same rule is applied for the third and fourth digits.

Example:

- 01 -> valid
- 00 -> not valid
- 0 -> not valid
- 1 -> valid

In short, zero value must not be allowed. How can I do this using Regex? or would it be better if I just do it with a javascript script?

Comment: Maybe `/^(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/`? See https://regex101.com/r/Gm9JH7/1. Please confirm you want to match only 1 to 3 digits before the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but 0 matches this regex. You could have a look at [this link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Anna, no, see https://regex101.com/r/Gm9JH7/1. It does not match `0`s. The `(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)` does not let the string be equal to `0`, `00000`, `000.00000`, `00000.0`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it actually works! My first regex allows 4 digits before the decimal separator. So I will just change what you gave me and put `{1,4}` instead of `{1,3}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ...but 001 matches, which is not a valid number. See https://regex101.com/r/Gm9JH7/2

Comment: @mlambrichs Right, see https://regex101.com/r/Gm9JH7/3. I added anothr check - `(?!00)` - to fail the case when there are 2 zeros at the start.

Comment: @Anna: I updated my solution and test cases.

Comment: @mlambrichs: 001 should be a valid number. I just don't want 000...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: thanks, problem solved ;)

Comment: @Anna Yeah, but for some unknown reason, DucFilan thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only match numbers that have 1 to 4 digits in the part before a decimal separator, and up to 2 digits after the decimal separator (I deduce it from the regex you used) *and* that do not start with `00` (that requirement comes from your verbal explanation), use

```
/^(?!00)(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)\d{1,~4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gm9JH7/5).

**Details**

- `^`- start of string
- `(?!00)` - no two `0`s at the start of the string
- `(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more `0`s, followed with an optional sequence of `.` or `,` followed with one or more zeros up to the string end
- `\d{1,4}` - any 1 to 4 digits
- `(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[.,]` - a `.` or `,`
  - `\d{1,2}` - any 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var ss = ['1','1.1','01','01.3','023.45','0','00','0.0','0.00','0001'];
var rx = /^(?!00)(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)\d{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/;
for (var s of ss) {
 var result = rx.test(s);
 console.log(s, "=>", result);
}
```

Comment: Note  I added a `0001` test case that I guess should fail. Thus, I added a `(?!00)` lookahead to make sure the numbers starting with `00` will get failed.

Comment: @DucFilan Then you have not clicked *Run code snippet*. Or you have not understood the question.

Comment: @DucFilan then you clearly see it works as per OP expectations: 1) no `00` at the start, 2) the number cannot equal `0`, 3) 1 to 3 digits before decimal separator and 2 digits after. Bro.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining JS and RegEx:

```
if (parseInt(value) != 0 && value.test(/\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?/)) {
    //valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a solution using only Regex :)